# Скрипт сам завершается выводя Killed

Tags: python

Написал дискорд бота, который каждую минуту проверяет на наличие нового репорта на сервере и отправляет сообщение в каналы, он работает, но спустя часов 10 работы сам по себе завершается, выводя Killed

Запускаю на дедике от timeweb.cloud (не реклама), конфигурация: 1 CPU • 1 Гб RAM • 15 Гб NVMe

Сам код:

```py
import threading, datetime, logging, nextcord, asyncio, httpx, random, time, json, os
from nextcord.ext import commands

import pandas

logging.basicConfig(format=u'%(filename)s [LINE:%(lineno)d] #%(levelname)-8s [%(asctime)s]  %(message)s', level=logging.INFO,)



bot_token = 'DISCORD BOT TOKEN'
channels_ids = [1084816637640851527,1132226371842752563]

translations = {'Lighthouse':'Маяк','Shoreline':'Берег','Woods':'Лес','Customs':'Таможня'}


intents = nextcord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(description="Goons Tracker", intents=intents)
#################################################################################################################################

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user} (ID: {bot.user.id})')

    await bot.change_presence(status=nextcord.Status.online, activity=nextcord.Activity(name="поиске гунов",type=nextcord.ActivityType.competing))#await bot.change_presence(status=nextcord.Status.online, activity=nextcord.CustomActivity(name="Ищет гунов", type=nextcord.ActivityType.custom))
    asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(goons_schedule())


@bot.slash_command(name='test')
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('извини',ephemeral=False)

async def get_url():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        goons_url = (await client.get('https://www.goontracker.com/static/js/bundle.js')).text.split('baseURL: "')[1].split('"')[0]
    return goons_url

async def find_goons():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        goons_url = await get_url()
        goons = (await client.get(f'{goons_url}goonDetectors/current')).json()
    goons_location = translations[goons["location"]]
    goons_date = (pandas.to_datetime(goons['lastReported']) + datetime.timedelta(hours=3)).strftime("%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S")
    goons_by = goons['reportedBy']
    goons_ID = goons['_id']
    return [goons_location, goons_date, goons_by, goons_ID]


async def goons_schedule():
    channels = []
    for x in channels_ids: channels.append(bot.get_channel(x))
    try:last_id = open('./temp',encoding='utf-8').read() #************************
    except:last_id = '************************'
    while True:
        try:
            goons = await find_goons()
            print('%s || %s'%(last_id,' --- '.join(goons)))
            if goons[3] != last_id:
                last_id = goons[3];open('./temp','w',encoding='utf-8').write(last_id)
                for channel in channels: await channel.send(f'Новый репорт!\nЛокация: **{goons[0]}**\nДата репорта: **{goons[1]}**\nID репортера: **{goons[2]}**')
            await asyncio.sleep(60)
        except Exception as e: logging.error(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.run(bot_token)
```

Comment: Ну это вам у хостера надо спрашивать, видимо, какие-то ограничения превышаете.